# I don't know how to write SQL syntax

Tags: mysql

I don't know how to write SQL syntax. For example:

```
SELECT username 
FROM login 
WHERE username='SELECT usr FROM employee WHERE status='Activ';
```

This query gives me an error.

How to write it?

Answer (score 1):

For your specific query, most likely, the subquery will return more than one row - so you need to use `IN` instead. Also, you don't quote subqueries, but put them in `()`:

```
SELECT username 
FROM login 
WHERE username IN 
    (select usr from employee where status='Activ');
```

This being said, you could/should use a join instead for this

```
SELECT login.username
FROM login 
INNER JOIN employee ON login.username = employee.usr
WHERE employee.status = 'Activ';
```

Comment: I will Try Dear,,
Thanks

Comment: Error Code : 1267
Illegal mix of collations (armscii8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:000
Error Dear?